# 80s animation, strange creature eating a human, green bird-face creature

Tags: mythology, story-identification

I remember an animation on VHS, it should be one of the 80s animations or maybe early 90s. A strange creature eating humans' body parts and then change to a woman, some other guy told her that she smells human and they will find out she's eaten a human. I remember they (maybe witches) found her and as a punishment threw her alive in a boiling oil. While she was frying alive, she turned into her true face. And also there was a war and a green creature who has wings, a human body with a birdlike face and his feet and hands were like birds' claws. I think it was a Japanese animation but not like a typical manga (with wide eyes...).
I hope someone know the name of this animation. I would really like to find it and watch it again.

Comment: wow that sounds horrifying!

Comment: Yeap, it truly was. But I love those strange images which remain on my mind all these years.

Comment: After having watched [some clips](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SABW6K_ZGkI) trying to identify this...I felt rather sick.

Comment: Sounds like a green harpy.  I don't recall any anime that matches your description, frankly.  It sounds more like something you'd find in [*Heavy Metal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy_Metal_%28film%29).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, might be *[Devilman](https://myanimelist.net/anime/2252/Devilman)*, possibly specifically *[Devilman: Yochou Sirene-hen](http://myanimelist.net/anime/2355/Devilman:_Yochou_Sirene-hen)*, which features a birdlike creature on the cover, the eponymous [Sirene](http://devilman.wikia.com/wiki/Sirene).

[image: DVD cover - Devilman: Yochou Sirene-hen]

> Demons exist and their power is beyond what humans can fathom. In fact they are so strong that humans do not stand a chance against them in a fight.
>
> The only thing strong enough to defeat a demon is another demon and it is trough this logic that Ryo Asuka hatches the plan to have his good-hearted friend Akira Fudo possessed by a demon. If a person is of pure of heart then he might be able to control the demon that posses him and thereby acquire power equal to a demon. After raising some hell in a club the plan works and Akira is possessed by the powerful demon known as Amon.
>
> Now Akira is humanities [sic] sole champion of justice against the hidden demon menace that has plagued humanity since the dawn of time.

In addition, the series is relatively gory.

Comment: Could you add details as to why you think it might be a match?

Comment: a human body with a birdlike face + gore